# How does the handling differ in PPT1 vs. PPT2?

Tags: puyo-puyo-tetris, puyo-puyo-tetris-2

I've seen a lot of Tetris players commenting on how Puyo Puyo Tetris 2 feels a bit slower compared to Puyo Puyo Tetris 1. Does anyone have exact frame counts and numbers for comparison?

(For context, I've heard speculation that the developers slightly increased the timing delays for Tetris to balance Puyo vs. Tetris play.)

I'm curious about specifics like ARE (spawn delay), lock delay, line clear delay, DAS (delayed auto shift), ARR (auto repeat rate), and SDF (soft drop factor).

I found the PPT1 timings on the Hard Drop wiki: https://harddrop.com/wiki/Puyo_Puyo_Tetris_timings

Does anyone know the timings for PPT2?